# Google domain is forwarded to an IP address on AWS(apparently) but I can't find it under instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, forward

Developer is MIA & I'm trying to figure out where the domain is hosted..
He said all domains are hosted is AWS, but I can't find the IP under instances (Public IP).
Hence wondering if he mis-stated.

I have the IP address where the google domain is being forwarded to.
When I do a who.is, it shows the below information:

> Amazon Technologies Inc. AT-88-Z (NET-3-0-0-0-1) 3.0.0.0 - 3.xxx.xxx.xxx
> Amazon Data Services NoVa AMAZON-IAD (NET-3-80-0-0-1) 3.80.0.0 - 3.95.255.255

Comment: Look through all AWS accounts in all regions. Check all instances, all gateways, all elastic ips, etc. until you find the ip.

Comment: Checked elastic-ips, route-53, DNS..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: You can't find it!

Long Answer:

This IP address could any of 100+ services AWS provides. It could be an EC2 instance. Did you checked all the regions? AWS has 25+ regions as of early 2022.

This could be Fargate instance under EKS or ECS. This could be any eni connected to various AWS services. It is really difficult to find like needle in a haystack.